# Cannot read property 'title' of undefined MEAN app

Tags: angular, database, mean

I've been getting this error and my form won't show up.

This is the code:

```html
<mat-card>
  <form (submit)="onSavePost(postForm)" #postForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        name="title"
        [ngModel]="post.title"
        required
        minlength="3"
        #title="ngModel"
      />
      <mat-error *ngIf="title.invalid">Please enter a post title.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <input
        matInput
        [ngModel]="post.content"
        name="content"
        required
        #content="ngModel"
      />
      <mat-error *ngIf="content.invalid">Please enter content</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit">Save Post</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

And the error picture:
[image: The error image]

Any ideas? I'm struggling with this for a long time haha, could use some help

Comment: Please check ***post*** value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the post.title, post is undefined yet.

Try this:

```
[ngModel]="post?.title"
```

Comment: No, it's not that my friend

Comment: Okay, and are you sure you have postId in paramMap?

Answer (score 3):

There is only one call of the `title` property: `post.title`. Seems like `post` is undefined. Probably page is rendered before the `post` is loaded.

Comment: I don't think so, this is my code
```enteredTitle = '';
  enteredContent = '';
  post: Post;
  private mode = 'create';
  private postId: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      if (paramMap.has('postId')) {
        this.mode = 'edit';
        this.postId = paramMap.get('postId');
        this.post = this.postsService.getPost(this.postId);
      } else {
        this.mode = 'create';
        this.postId = null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The initial value of the `post` property is undefined. Rendering would happen before the subscription to the route params would trigger. So, the answer I provided describes exactly what is happening. The accepted answer would work well for the case because `this.postsService.getPost` is synchronous method. with async it would have been a poor user experience